# How to handle a pop up in Microsoft Excel using excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm want to write an excel macro to handle some pop-up from microsoft excel (click on the OK button or fill in some empty fields).
I did quite a lot of googling but still couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: You will need to provide significantly more detail for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: @brettdj It's just about how to perform some simple actions on excel's pop up. So what kind of details do you need? :)

Comment: What causes the pop-up to appear in the first place?

Comment: What pop-up would be a useful start

Comment: got what you mean, I'm writing some Gherkin tests to test a web app,
In one test case, I use some excel macros to fill up some fields in the excel file. So what triggers the pop-up is also an excel macro. I want write an additional excel macro (just to use for Gherkin test) to handle the pop-up. The pop-up has a empty test field and a "OK" button. Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is not capable of monitoring pop-up modal windows and at the same time executing code to "Dismiss" these modal windows. You can either have another external application waiting for the pop-up window to appear then "Click" or "SendKeys" to them.

Here is a similar question

[Filling Excel userform in excel file automatically from vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228146/filling-excel-userform-in-excel-file-automatically-from-vbscript/13228214#13228214)